# Nuxt 3 Page Transition and Layout Transition Not Working

Tags: javascript, css, animation, vuejs3, nuxt3

I'm trying to implement the layout transition in my nuxt 3 project didnt work. I even went as far as to copy the same code from the [nuxt transition docs][1] only for it to also fail please help. Here is my code

app.vue file

```
    <div>
    <NuxtLayout>
      <NuxtPage/>
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>



<style>
    .layout-enter-active, 
    .layout-leave-active {
        transition: opacity 2s;
    }
    .layout-enter-from, 
    .layout-leave-to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>

nuxt.config.ts file
    export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    layoutTransition: {
      name: 'layout', 
       mode: 'out-in'}
  },
  modules: ['nuxt-icon', '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'],
  css: ['~/assets/css/main.css'],
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    }, 
  },
  pages: true,
  // nuxtIcon: {
  //   size: '30px', // default <Icon> size applied
  //   class: 'icon', // default <Icon> class applied
  //   aliases: {
  //     'nuxt': 'logos:nuxt-icon',
  //   }
  // }
})


  [1]: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/transitions
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to double check your codes and see if there are any conflicts that is causing the transition issue. I have created an example based on the codes given and it is working. No issues at all

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  app: {
    layoutTransition: { name: 'layout', mode: 'out-in' }
  },
})
```

`app.vue`

```js
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>

<style>
.layout-enter-active,
.layout-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
.layout-enter-from,
.layout-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Here is a working example link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-su263d?file=nuxt.config.ts

Hope that helps you.